# Difference between files cat /etc/logrotate.conf and cat /etc/logrotate.d and cat /etc/cron.daily/logrotate

Tags: logrotate

I am new to logrotate. I am seeing three files `/etc/logrotate.conf` and `/etc/logrotate.d` and `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate` which are essential to the logrotate functioning. But I'm not able to understand their individual working and significance. Can someone explain to me what is the significance of these two files? And what are the other files important for logrotate and where are they located?

Comment: Is `cat` part of the filename. Or are you under the misconception that it make it clearer?

Comment: Not a part of the filename

Comment: What does `cat /etc/logrotate.d` do on your system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/etc/logrotate.conf` is the main configuration file for logrotate.

It can be useful to separate out configurations for specific services or functions though, so one of the things that `/etc/logrotate.conf` likely has specified in it is the line `include /etc/logrotate.d`.

This line tells the logrotate process to also include config files under `/etc/logrotate.d`. Doing so allows you to break out logrotate configurations into separate files instead of one large configuration file.

Finally `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate` is a cronjob that runs once a day (as all jobs under `/etc/cron.daily` do). Its purpose is to execute the logrotate command once per day so that any logs that meet the criteria of `/etc/logrotate.conf` or any files under `/etc/logrotate.d` will get rotated.

Comment: Do you have any idea about nagios logrotation? I really need help with it

Comment: Sure, nagios uses its own method to rotate logs. In the `nagios.cfg` file there is an entry called `log_rotation_method`. It can be set to n, h, d, w, or m. n = None (don't rotate the log - this is the default), h = Hourly (rotate the log at the top of each hour), d = Daily (rotate the log at midnight each day), w = Weekly (rotate the log at midnight on Saturday), m = Monthly (rotate the log at midnight on the last day of the month). So if you wanted to set nagios logs to rotate daily the line would read. `log_rotation_method=d`.

Comment: Where is this file located? Not able to find the directory where log_rotation_method is specified. Please help

Comment: `nagios.cfg` is at `/etc/nagios/nagios.cfg` for my system. `log_rotation_method` is an entry in that file. If it is not specified then add it with whatever value matches your needs and restart the nagios service.